# SQL query sum unique records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I'm trying to sum all sales of one period of time of a selling vehicle. The problem is that every product sold is one row whit amount and price and a total of the bill and the bill number.

So I have 2 options: multiply ever sold product amount whit the price and sum that. Or take the bill remove double rows and sum that. I chosen for the second option.

So now I have a [Location Code] (selling vehicle), [Bill No] and a [Total Price].

So I get:

```
0001    0001/00277343   10,26000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277343   10,26000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277343   10,26000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277343   10,26000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277345   10,33000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277345   10,33000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277345   10,33000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277347   24,35000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277348   30,31000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277348   30,31000000000000000000
0001    0001/00277349   2,69000000000000000000
```

As you see double entries, because on one bill there are more than one item. So now I just want to sum the unique price so that I get

0001    1822,50

At this moment I'm only as far as this:

```
select [Location Code], [Bill No_] , Price from [Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Location Code] = '0001' and [Document Date] = '01.04.2015'
```

I tried several but none is working.  Best result gives this, but not summed

```
select distinct[Bill No_], [Location Code] , Price from [Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Location Code] = '0001' and [Document Date] = '01.04.2015'
```

Comment: Where did you get `1822,50` from?

Comment: Are you sure it's correct to sum up all "distinct" prices? If more cars are sold on one bill and both cars have the same price then taking the amount in consideration only once is not a correct scenario, I think.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I tried already, but that I get each bill separately (so 105 rows) not a sum of only one day (so 1 row). I use Toad for SQL on a 2012 SQL server. I don't want to sum the distinct price but the distinct bills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT [Location Code], [Bill No_], SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT [Location Code], [Bill No_] , Price from [Item Ledger Entry] 
      WHERE [Location Code] = '0001' and [Document Date] = '01.04.2015') t
GROUP BY [Location Code], [Bill No_]
```

Comment: Almost, but I made it work the way I want to. Thanks:
SELECT [Location Code],  SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT [Location Code], [Bill No_] , Price from [Item Ledger Entry] 
      WHERE [Location Code] = '0001' and [Document Date] = '01.04.2015') t
GROUP BY [Location Code]

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Location Code], [Bill No_] , SUM(Price) from [Item Ledger Entry] 
where [Location Code] = '0001' and [Document Date] = '01.04.2015'
group by [Location Code], [Bill No_]
```